# Sails.js Jade template engine extremely slow

Tags: node.js, pug, sails.js

I use sails.js in my project with jade template engine enabled and noticed pages load very slow. (up to 5 seconds).
As far as I understand pages being recompiled each request.
Is any way to force jade to compile views just when application starts and only pass variables each requests to it and render?
Or any other options could be handled to make jade a reasonable option.

this what I have in config/views.js

> module.exports.views = {
>
> engine: 'jade',

and following  dependencies in package json

> "dependencies": {
>       "sails": "0.9.16",
>       "grunt": "0.4.1",
>       "sails-disk": "~0.9.0",
>       "sails-memory": "~0.9.1",
>       "then-jade": "~2.0.0",
>       "optimist": "0.3.4",
>       "node-rest-client": "*",
>       "moment":"*",
>       "request":"*"   },

Comment: Are those cached? Don't you have an option to change jade's debug property? It makes a big difference

Comment: Are you doing anything else in your application? Template rendering, even including a reload, tends to be very fast. Not in the “seconds” range, certainly, unless you happen to have particularly enormous templates.

Comment: I just updated sails to last version (0.10.5) and that required  "jade"  module, not "then-jade"   ... That fixed my problem.